# How to share a Smart Album in Photos App

Tags: appletv, photos.app

I am using the new Photos app in OSX and would like to share recent photos with the Apple TVs in my house by using Home Sharing.  The photos would be used for the screen saver feature on the Apple TV.  It seems as though the best way to do it is to use a Smart Album and set the Date range.

However, it seems as though Smart Albums cannot be accessed using Home Sharing as they do not appear as an option in the Apple TV screen saver settings.

Does anyone know if it is possible to share Smart Albums using Home Sharing?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy:

1. close iTunes if it is open
2. have your smart albums created on photos app
3. still on Photos, create a new folder and named it with a unique name like
4. "Vacations 2018"
5. click on your smart album(s) and drag it(them) into the folder you just created
6. close the photos app
7. open iTunes, go to File -> Home Sharing -> choose photos to share with AppleTV
8. Select Share Photos from: Photos
9. click on Selected Albums (Select "Inlude Videos" checkbox if you want them played as well)
10. In the Albums collection, click on the folder you created at the beginning (Vacations 2018)
11. click the button Done at the bottom of the screen
12. close iTunes
13. Go to your AppleTV and select Settings -> General -> Screensaver -> Home Sharing -> Type -> Home Sharing -> Home Sharing -> Photos -> Photos. Confirm that you want to set photos as your screen saver
14. go back to the screensaver windows and choose the Preview option to confirm the photos are corrected select and displayed.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

did you sort this in the end? It should pop up as an album as any others do. Works for me. I'm doing the same thing as you, but trying to share a smart album on cloud photos.